# Are solid materials ergodic systems?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, metals, ergodicity

It is stated that a system is considered ergodic if it can access all available states with the same energy in the phase space over long periods of time and that time average and ensemble average of some quantity yield the same result.

How does this apply to finite solids, especially metals?

Are they considered ergodic since the atoms can diffuse all over the place (at some temperature $T > 0$ K) for infinte timescales in the crystalline phase and thus the system can explore the entire phase space?

I know from metallic glasses with an amorphous structure, that these are said to be ergodic in the supercooled liquid phase, as they are liquids, but are said to be non-ergodic in the glass state below the glass transition temperature. But this confuses me because the atoms can still diffuse below this finite threshold temperature.

Any thoughts on this topic are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the distinction between ergodic and non-ergodic materials is made based on whether the observable material properties correspond to phase-space average or time-average properties.

Consider the 2d-Ising model to have a simple example in mind. Below the critical temperature the magnetization shows two branches. If the phase-space average is calculated, then the mean magnetization is zero. If the time-average is calculated, then the magnetization is on one of those two branches, because the kinetic barrier to get out of that branch is so very large and does not allow to transition to the other branch in finite simulation time.